# ¿Por qué es importante dar un valor inicial a un HashMap

Tags: java

Estoy estudiando las colecciones en java y hay algo que no entiendo de la parte teórica; agradecería muchísimo si alguien fuera tan amable de responder mi duda.

Según este párrafo:

"HashSet: este implementación almacena los elementos en una tabla hash. Es la implementación con mejor rendimiento de todas pero no garantiza ningún orden a la hora de realizar iteraciones. Es la implementación más empleada debido a su rendimiento y a que, generalmente, no nos importa el orden que ocupen los elementos. Esta implementación proporciona tiempos constantes en las operaciones básicas siempre y cuando la función hash disperse de forma correcta los elementos dentro de la tabla hash. **Es importante definir el tamaño inicial de la tabla ya que este tamaño marcará el rendimiento de esta implementación**."

La parte en negrita, ¿alguien me puede decir por qué es importante definir el tamaño inicial de este tipo de colecciones? Y ¿en función a qué se debe definir?

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Quizas este post te ayude https://medium.com/@moltenma/why-is-better-to-define-the-hashmap-initial-size-7b385bcebf7d

Comment: Por defecto el tamaño inicial es 16 (ver [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)) y es necesario porque de este modo no se tendrá que crear un búfer y copiar los elementos del anterior búfer al nuevo cada vez que se añade un elemento al hashmap. Por esa razón se usa un tamaño inicial, esto reduce dicho proceso que mencioné anteriormente.